# Detect a Price In Brackets in a String (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm looking to analyse strings in PHP. They appear as such:

Premium Upgrade (€10.00)

I want to detect when a string contains '(€10.00)', however the price will change. Hence I'm guessing a RegEx for 'Bracket, Float, Bracket' The end result is I want to remove the price from the string, however, its possible something else may appear in the brackets e.g.

Premium Upgrade (Per Person)

And hence I can't just explode or substring on the first opening brackets. However, there could be two, or more, brackets e.g.

Premium Upgrade (Per Person) (€10.00)

Hence in this instance, I would need to output:

Premium Upgrade (Per Person)

Thus my high level flow would be:

- Check string, does it contact brackets and float?
- Yes, remove the brackets and float, leaving other brackets in place, proceed.
- No brackets and float? Leave as is, proceed.

My pysedo code is:

```
//Get my string
$str = $meta->display_key;

//I need a RegEx here to detect my bracket and float e.g. (€X.YY)
if (strpos($str, '(') !== false) {
    //Need to remove brackets and float here, but leave all other brackets in place.
    $formatted_string  = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '('));
}

//Do nothing, the string doesn't match my criteria
else $display_key_formatted = $str;
```

Comment: Soooo… you have looked into regexen for this? Because that would make it pretty trivial.

Comment: Try [`preg_replace('~\s*\(\p{Sc}\d[\.\d]*\)~u', '', $s)`](https://regex101.com/r/anPyfI/1).

Comment: Any feedback? Please check the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a price in brackets that is in the `(`+`CURRENCY_SYMBOL`+`FLOAT_OR_INT_NUMBER`+`)` you may use

```
$res = preg_replace('~\s*\(\p{Sc}\d[.\d]*\)~u', '', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/anPyfI/2)

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(`
- `\p{Sc}` - any currency char
- `\d` - a digit
- `[.\d]*` - 0+ chars that are either `.` or a digit
- `\)` - a `)`

See the PHP demo:

```
$re = '/\s*\(\p{Sc}\d[.\d]*\)/u';
$str = ' TEXT (text) (€10.00)';
$res = preg_replace($re, '', $str);
echo $res; // =>  TEXT (text)
```

Comment: This appears to work. Thank you Wiktor, I very much appreciate the time taken to explain each line.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for a regex like: `!\((.\d+\.\d+\))!` that should match anything with a currency and a price within brackets.